# creating IPA for enterprise app and not an ad hoc

Tags: xcode, shell, enterprise, ipa, adhoc

i'm trying to create a script for an ipa file for my app, but i want it to be for enterprise distribution and not an Ad Hoc.

my script is:

```
# creating xcArchive file

xcodebuild -workspace <ProjectName>.xcworkspace -scheme <SchemeName> archive \
-archivePath <DirectoryPath><ScemeName>.xcarchive


# compressing the xcArchive file into IPA file
xcodebuild \
-exportArchive \
-exportFormat ipa \
-archivePath <DirectoryPath>/<ScemeName>.xcarchive \
-exportPath <DirectoryPath>/<ScemeName>.ipa" \
        -exportProvisioningProfile "<My Distribution Provisioning Profile>".
```

Now, in apple wizard, when i'm creating an IPA file, in its embedded.mobileprovision i can see those attributes:
for eneterprise distribution:

```
 <key>ProvisionsAllDevices</key>
 <true/>
```

for Ad-Hoc distribution:

```
<key>ProvisionedDevices</key>
    <array>
        <string>accacaca0-9800ac898a908908c90aca890c8a90</string>
        <string>123123123123123123bfd123bdf123fv123bdf12</string>
.
.
.
    </array>
```

In my case, i don't know why, i don't have any of them, and therefore cannot install them on any device.
anyone can tell me why is it ? please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I should use a modern approach, and write it in export.plist:

```
#
# creating .xcarchive file from .app file
function create_archive_file() {
    xcodebuild \
    -workspace ${PROJECT_NAME}.xcworkspace \
    -scheme "${scheme_name}" \
    archive \
    -archivePath ${SRCROOT}/${proj_external_name}/${1}.xcarchive
}
#
# compressing xcArchive file into IPA file
function create_ipa_from_archive() {
    xcrun xcodebuild \
    -exportArchive \
    -archivePath ${SRCROOT}/${proj_external_name}/${scheme_name}.xcarchive \
    -exportPath ${SRCROOT}/${proj_external_name}/folder \
    -exportOptionsPlist export.plist
}
```

and in export.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>teamID</key>
    <string>... (my TeamID, get it from one archiving action only once, and check it's details in build editor)</string>
    <key>method</key>
    <string>enterprise</string>
    <key>uploadSymbols</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: And this works? I am seeing an error: "Error Domain=IDEDistributionErrorDomain Code=14 "No applicable devices found." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No applicable devices found.}" with same commands on plist content. What are the singing settings in your project? Automatic?

Comment: It worked for me.
I think (It's little late in my region) maybe your provision profile shouldn't be for specific devices, it should be wildcard.

Comment: It is not. I am using enterprise profile that can be used with any device. I am not the only one having this problem (based on googling). It seems, or could be, that for some reason it tries to use ad-hoc method even though enterprise is defined.

Comment: In my case the reason why it did not work was use of google-cast-sdk and this bug: code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=954

Comment: Check if the right provisioning profile is also in your target